# What is the pattern matched against for events CmdwinLeave and CmdwinEnter?

Tags: command-line, autocmd, pattern, events

More in general I'm always in doubt about what's the meaning of the `{aupat}` argument of `autocmd` for a given `{event}`.

From `:help :autocmd` I read (my emphasis)

> Add {cmd} to the list of commands that Vim will execute automatically on {event} **for a file matching {aupat} autocmd-patterns**.

So from here it looks like `{aupat}` is always used maybe not to match a file name, but more in general to match a file. This kind of makes sense for events like `BufWriteCmd`, where `{aupat}` truly matching a file name, and `FileType`, where it matches the file type of the file.

But there are other events for which there's no such a thing as a file related to it. One example is `ColorScheme`, for which

> The pattern is matched against the colorscheme name

reading directly from `:help ColorScheme`.

But not the documentation of all `{event}`s seem to explain what `{aupat}` means for them.

For instance, the word *pattern* doesn't even appear in `:help CmdwinLeave` and `:help CmdwinEnter`.

Hence the question: what is `{aupat}` matched against for `{event}`s `CmdwinLeave` and `CmdwinEnter`?

Comment: I believe it's matched against the type of command window entered, a single character. See: `:help cmdwin-char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those things are easy to test with `:help <amatch>`:

```
autocmd! CmdWinLeave * echomsg expand('<amatch>')
```

Where you use a wildcard to catch every possible case and echo `<amatch>` in the messages.

You get `:` when leaving `q:` and `/` when leaving `q/`, which lets you know what `{aupat}` to use in your autocommand:

```
autocmd! CmdWinLeave / <do something when leaving the search command-line window>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation makes this clear I believe:

[:h CmdwinLeave](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CmdwinLeave) mentions this:

```
<afile> is set to a single character,
indicating the type of command-line.
|cmdwin-char|
```

(same for [:h CmdwinEnter](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CmdwinEnter))

Note the `|cmdwin-char|`, which references another help topic, [:h cmdwin-char](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdwin-char), which finally answers your question:

```
The character used for the pattern indicates the type of command-line:
        :       normal Ex command
        >       debug mode command debug-mode
        /       forward search string
        ?       backward search string
        =       expression for "= expr-register
        @       string for input()
        -       text for :insert or :append
```

Comment: I had read that, but that doesn't say that `<afile>` is what `{aupat}` is matched against. My confusion is mostly expressed by the paragraph in my question that follows the first quote.